# Sudden frame rate drops on mobile when instantiating/destroying?

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I am currently working on a mobile game and I can't help but notice that whenever an object (an obstacle in my case) is instantiated or destroyed, I get a sudden FPS drop which is critical for my gameplay.

To help give an idea, I instantiate obstacles on top of my screen every 1.5 seconds, then I scroll them down. If the obstacles reaches the bottom of the screen already, I destroy them to prevent memory leaks/waste.

I'm still pretty new to Unity development. Am I on the right track though? What is a better solution to prevent this sudden frame rate drop?

Comment: How many tri's are in the bject which you are attempting to instantiate ? See - http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=General_Performance_Tips

Comment: @Zze Thanks for the comment.Not a lot. It's basically just a simple sprite with a box collider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any big / nested loops or complex processes going off as part of instantiation (Look at your awake/start methods)?

Regardless, look into [object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) as a better method to handle this type of thing.

For a basic example, instead of creating/destroying projectiles of a gun every time it's used, give that gun a "projectile pool" that creates n projectiles when the level loads. Then, when shooting, just set the projectile's position back to the gun and set the projectile as active. After impact, have the projectile deactivate (or after a few seconds if nothing is hit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have any complex loops. The object I'm instantiating and destroying is a 2D sprite with a box collider. But I will look into the object pooling you suggested. Sounds like it would do the trick